# Merging in R: looking for options similar to SAS merge output options

Tags: r, merge, sas

This is my first question to StackOverflow.  I apologize in advance if my question is not polished or clear.

When merging in SAS, it is possible to output rows without matches to alternate datasets.

For instance,

```
data matched nomatch_a nomatch_b;  
    merge A(in=a) B(in=b);  
    by var;  
    if a and b then output matched;  
    else if a and not b then output nomatch_a;  
    else if b and not a then output nomatch_b;
```

In this case:
- the rows that are successfully merged are outputted to matched
- the rows in dataset A that did not have matches in B are outputted to nomatch_a
- and the rows in dataset B that did not have matches in A are outputted to nomatch_b.

I'm looking to do something similar in R.  It doesn't have to be a one-liner but I would like an elegant solution.  I know that there are all.x, all.y options but I can't quite tweak those options to get what I want.  I would appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: What are you trying to merge?  Data frames, vectors, matrices, etc.?  Would be helpful to create a small example of what your input and output data should look like, readable directly into R.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #if a and b then output matched;  

matched <- merge(a,b, by= "var")
```

The 'all' argument is FALSE by default, which gives you the "inner join".

```
#    else if a and not b then output nomatch_a;  

nomatch_a <- a[ !a$var %in% unique(b$var) , ]

#    else if b and not a then output nomatch_b;  

nomatch_b <- b[ !b$var %in% unique(a$var) ,  ]
```

The second two assignments construct logical vectors and use the "[" function to extract entire rows just for the TRUE rows. I don't think there are any one-liners, but then you can hardly call that SAS proc a one-liner can you? I suppose you could first use `all=TRUE` and then do a similar extract from the "full outer join" value but it seemed simpler to do it as above, to me anyway.